# Django REST framework, content negotiation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get my endpoint to return a `uri-list` when asked for that and a json string as default. I am testing this in a unit test looking a bit like:

```
[...]
headers = {'Accept': 'text/uri-list'}
response = self.client.get('/api/v1/licenses/', headers=headers)
[...]
```

I have written a `URIListRenderer` like this:

```
from rest_framework import renderers


class URIListRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
media_type = 'text/uri-list'

def render(self, data, media_type='None', renderer_context=None):
    return "\n".join(data).encode()
```

Next I am trying to get my Response in my View to be rendered using my renderer:

```
class RestLicenses(APIView):    
    """
    List all licenses, or create a new license
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, URIListRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, format=None,):
        models = LicenseModel.objects.all()
        if len(models) == 0 :
            return Response('[]',status=204)
        if request.META.get('headers') is not None :
            if request.META.get('headers').get('Accept') == 'text/uri-list' :
                result = [];
                for m in models :
                    result.append(reverse('downloadLicense', args=[m.pk], request=request))
                return Response(result, status=200)

        serializer = LicenseJSONSerializer(request, models, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid()
        return HttpResponse(JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data), content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

But it seems impossible to get it to choose any other renderer than the first one in the list. How do I make it choose my `URIListRenderer` and not the json one?

Comment: Have you debugged what `request.META.get('headers').get('Accept')` actually returns? `==` is a rather strict comparison type as strings go.

Comment: It returns true, but it seems that the actual content negotiation takes place some completely different location and it always ends up with it picking the first renderer class.

Comment: Does the request have `?format=json` as query parameter by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unit test is not setting the headers correctly. As described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get), you should use CGI style headers when using the Django test client:

```
response = self.client.get('/api/v1/licenses/', HTTP_ACCEPT='text/uri-list')
```

The content negotiation uses the real HTTP Accept header. In your code, you check that "headers" is set, but that's not the real HTTP Accept header. It should be:

```
if request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT') == "text/uri-list":
    ...
```

Comment: Exactly! after checking how the renderers are matched, I also concluded the header is not coming in correctly but I totally missed that part where he isn't setting it correctly in the test

Answer (score 1):

This is a block of code from the method `finalize_response`:

```
if isinstance(response, Response):
    if not getattr(request, 'accepted_renderer', None):
        neg = self.perform_content_negotiation(request, force=True)
        request.accepted_renderer, request.accepted_media_type = neg

    response.accepted_renderer = request.accepted_renderer
    response.accepted_media_type = request.accepted_media_type
    response.renderer_context = self.get_renderer_context()
```

As you can see, before it performs content negotiaton, it checks to see if the view has already set the renderer needed and if not tries to perform the negotiation by itself. 
So you can do this in your get method:

```
if request.META.get('headers') is not None :
        if request.META.get('headers').get('Accept') == 'text/uri-list' :
            request.accepted_renderer = URIListRenderer
            result = [];
            for m in models :
                result.append(reverse('downloadLicense', args=[m.pk], request=request))
            return Response(result, status=200)
```

Another thing you should probably do is to place your custom renderer class before `JSONRenderer` in the renderer_classes list. In that way, it will first check the special case before the more general case during content negotiation. Is suspect that the request format also matches JSOnRender and it overshadows the custom renderer. Hope this helps

Comment: This shouldn't be needed. Setting the `accepted_renderer` will work, but why it's not matched using the default negotiation is strange. The `JSONRenderer` has only "application/json" as media type, so it shouldn't catch that one. Also you should set the `accepted_renderer` after the second `if` condition.

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah, I have fixed it.